# Android Facebook taggable friend photo size

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm able to query taggable friend from facebook but the photo url return is too small. 
Is there a way to get a larger photo?

I tried everything I could think of but still won't work.

```
Request request = new Request(session,"/me/taggable_friends,",null,HttpMethod.GET);
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putInt("width", 100);
params.putInt("height", 100);
request.setParameters(params);
```

also tried something like this

```
Request request = new Request(session,"/me/taggable_friends?height=100,width=100",null,HttpMethod.GET);
```

Below is my code for handling the session, I don't have a login button for my application

```
private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception
{
    if(session.isClosed())
    {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, callback);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Settings.addLoggingBehavior( LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS );
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null)
    {
        //if session is either closed or open we go to session state change
        //else we open it 
        if(session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) 
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        else
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_friends")).setCallback(callback));
    }
}
```

Here's the callback

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
};
```

Please tell me if you know the solution, appreciate it.

Comment: how about /me/taggable_friends?type=large

Comment: I tried that, got error.
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}, isFromCache:false}

Comment: Looks like the error is related to not passing an auth-token or passing an incorrect/old one.

Comment: But this error did not happen if I don't include the modifier "?type=large".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
me/taggable_friends?fields=name,picture.width(400).height(400)
```

Keep in mind that those are minimum values, so you may get pictures that are "at least 400x400".

Another possibility:

```
me/taggable_friends?fields=name,picture.type(large)
```

I am no Android developer, but this is how it may work:

```
Request request = new Request(session,"me/taggable_friends", null, HttpMethod.GET);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("fields", "name,picture.width(400).height(400)");
request.setParameters(bundle);
```

Comment: Both return error from facebook.
"An active access token must be used to query information about thecurrent user". I have checked that the token is opened, not expires, has enough permission.

Comment: i tested it in the api explorer with user_friends. works fine, so there must be something wrong with your access token...or you dont add it to the call correctly.

Comment: I've updated my post to include the code for session handling. I don't have a login button for my application. Would you please go through it and tell me if there's any error? Thank you.

Comment: I tried to login with another facebook account which is not admin or developer of that application. It returned error and tell me to use taggable friends I need to submit the application for review. I just want to display a list of facebook friends, I am using taggable friends since newMyFriendsRequest now only return friend that also using the application.

Comment: for only displaying a list of facebook friends, you are not allowed to use taggable_friends, and it will never get approved for that. /me/friends only returns friends using the app for a good reason: privacy. no friend should be visible in the app if he did not even authorize it.

Comment: that say if my application was a test application that no one will ever install, I will never able to get any list of friends?

Comment: you mean, if it´s NOT a test application? because THEN you would not be able to get a list of ALL friends. you can always get a list of friends who authorized the app though. anyway, that´s a completely different topic and answered in many threads on stackoverflow already.

Comment: on topic: make sure you fix your code, as it works perfectly fine in the api explorer you surely did something wrong. for example: params.putInt("fields", "name,picture.width(400).height(400)"); - not sure if that´s how it works, i am no android developer. but as it is right now it´s obviously wrong.

Comment: You are right, just have to specify the parameter like you mention. I'll include the answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve IDs using friends_taggable, and then use IDs like:

```
/0101010101/picture?redirect=true&height=200&type=square&width=200
```

Replace 0101010101 with the ID you want.

Basically you can call this http address and read the picture data directly:

```
"http://graph.facebook.com/" + id
            + "/picture?redirect=true&height=200&type=square&width=200
```

Comment: you only get a "tagging token" with taggable_friends, i just tried using the picture endpoint with that token and it does not work. it would also be a separate call for every single friend, that would be a LOT of calls...

Answer (score 0):

```
Request request = new Request(session,"me/taggable_friends",null,HttpMethod.GET);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("fields", "name,picture.type(large)");
request.setParameters(bundle);
```

Here's the solution, hope it helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has since updated its Library and now the correct way on (4.1.0) is:

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("limit","1000");
    params.putString("fields", "id,name,picture.width(256).height(256)");
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/taggable_friends",
            params,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                       if(graphResponse != null(){
                             // ... handle the result

                       }
                    }
            }).executeAsync();
```